# AWS s3 object boto3, how to stream upload while streaming download

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a function that gets an object from one bucket and uploads it to another bucket. My file sizes are unpredictable so what I do is give my memory more than what I need most of the time.

Ideally what I want to do is stream the download/upload so I do not have to give it more memory than what it needs.

1. Stream download from bucketA (a *chunk* at a time)
2. Stream upload to bucketB
3. Remove uploaded chunk from buffer
4. repeat step 1 until all chunks have been transferred

This way, I'm only buffering the chunk size during the whole process.

So far I know that streaming download is possible

```
 response = s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key=file)

 
 for i,line in enumerate(response['Body'].iter_lines()):
    # upload line by line
```

How do I do I upload per "line" with `put_object` and also validating integrity with md5 hash?

Comment: Are you copying the entire object? If so, you can use `copy_object()` to tell S3 to copy the object. This works between buckets and even between regions and AWS accounts. The copy takes place entirely within S3, so there is no need to Download and Upload.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein does it with GovCloud?

Comment: @edmamerto Yes, that shouldn't prevent anything

Comment: It probably won't copy between GovCloud and a non-GovCloud region because they use different credential sets.

Comment: is it possible though with assume roles @JohnRotenstein

Comment: Do you have a requirement to copy objects between AWS GovCloud and 'normal' AWS? If so, please add that to your question.

Comment: You can use AssumeRoles, but if you wish to use `copy_object()`, then the IAM Role that you assume must have permission to both read from the source bucket and write to the destination bucket. The `copy_object()` API call can only use a _single_ set of credentials, not two sets of credentials.